Collatz conjecture and prime numbers
With the intention of understanding how prime numbers contribute to the numerical results we get when we perform any possible numerical calculation (also on real numbers), since they are those natural numbers with which all other natural numbers can be created, and natural numbers, through the 4 operations and power elevation, can create all real numbers (sometimes even with infinite summations), I was thinking of a numerical problem in which it was fairly easy to exclude prime numbers from the arithmetic used. The choice fell on the Collatz conjecture.
I have already read some interesting threads in this site about the contribution of the prime numbers in making the sequence always arrive at $1$, that is, always arrive at a power of $2$.
I did a simple test with code, and in the code I simply put a check that if the odd number is prime then I multiply it by $3$ and add $2$ instead of $1$, or I just multiply it by $3$, that is, if I get a prime number in the sequence, I force it to become the odd number next or previous to the even number I get with the standard $3n+1$ operation.
Starting from some random numbers for $n$, I noticed, as can be imagined based on some related threads on this site, that the sequence never ends if the prime numbers are always excluded. I don't have a demonstration of this and have done few number of testing.
The code is as follows:
import math
from sympy import *

def collatz(n):
    while n>1:
        f,i = math.modf(n/2.)
        if f==0.:
            n=int(i)
            print(n)
        else:
            if isprime(n):
                #n1=3*n+1   -1
                n1=3*n+1   +1
                n=n1
                print(n)
            else:
                n=3*n+1
                print(n)

collatz(17)

Questions



Are the prime numbers that could allow the conjecture to always end, even if we don't know for now if it always ends? Can this be explained with some sort of demonstration?




Are all other ways of excluding prime numbers always equivalent to the two I used (in the code)?




Are there some information/studies on what is the probability with which a power of $2$ is obtained, with $3n+1$ operation, starting, for $n$, from:


a) an odd number that is not prime
b) an odd number that is prime? For probability I mean number of times we obtain a power of $2$ over the total number of odd non-prime numbers chosen and over the total number of prime numbers chosen.



Edit (to clarify, I hope)
Sorry for my poor synthesis skills.
I did some other tests and I saw that with the modification $3n+2$ instead of $3n+1$ to be applied when a prime number is encountered in the sequence, I obtain the end of the algorithm, obviously by avoiding numbers that are power of $2$, if I start from:

all those odd non-prime numbers like $21$, $85$, ... that give a power of $2$ (in particular $2^{even}$) if the rule $3n+1$ is applied (i.e. sequence A: $21\cdot2^{n}$, $85\cdot2^{n}$, $341\cdot2^{n}$, ...);
all those even numbers that are just before the odd numbers above (sequence A with the exception of $21$), like $84$, $340$, ... (i.e. sequence B: $84\cdot2^{n}$, $340\cdot2^{n}$, $1364\cdot2^{n}$, ...), because dividing them by $2$ several times, gives an odd number of the sequence A when $n=0$. But I'm not completely sure about it (I can't prove it).

So, there are starting numbers (counterexamples, such as sequence A and B) that cause the modified algorithm, with $3n+2$ instead of $3n+1$ when there is a prime number, to terminate, also without prime numbers in the sequence, with the exception of $2$ (that is always inside the sequence if algorithm ends). This confirms that I was rather imprecise and incomplete in my first post.
Another approach could be to eliminate the prime numbers with the modification:
...
if isprime(n):
    n1=n+1
    #or n1=n-1, ...
    n=n1
...

but for now I want to focus on different operation on primes (like $3n+2$) instead of change immediately the prime, in the algorithm, to the following or previous number.
Two questions that summarize my curiosity about this problem, I hope to clarify things better (as requested):

Are there other sequences different from A and B that allow the algorithm posted at the beginning to terminate when one starts with a number of these different sequences?
With a more mathematical approach (or with other counterexamples that I have not found so far), how could one understand or intuit that, with the rule $3n+2$ (or similar) to be applied only when one finds a prime number, is it possible or not to arrive to a certain number that terminates the algorithm and does not belong to the sequences A and B, excluding the numbers of the sequences A and B as initial numbers?


The rules are not clear.  I gather you follow the ordinary Collatz rules except when you hit an odd prime.  Odd primes, $p$,  are either mapped to $3p$ or to $3p+2$...but how do you decide which?    In any case, it can hardly be true that "the sequence never ends" since some sequences don't contain any primes (if you start with a power of $2$, for example).

I suggest:  try to edit for clarity.  Sentences like "Are the prime numbers that could allow the conjecture to always end, even if we don't know for now if it always ends?" really don't make any sense.

@lulu, hi, yes I'll edit my post to explain better, I'll just take a little time to organize the thoughts in the mind.

Anyway from what I understand the sequence ends every time it reaches a power of $2$, because by dividing by $2$ one obtains always $1$ at end, and test finishes.
So I consider "trivial" a starting number that is a power of $2$ ($2$ is prime but we finish always with $1$, so in my test I never start from a power of $2$).

Let's say that it comes naturally to me to believe that the prime numbers play a key role in making the conjecture true for all natural numbers as starting number and with that particular formula for odd numbers ($3n+1$).

But I am well aware that conjectures can be more numerous than the atoms in the universe. I'd just like to see if it makes sense to take an approach that attempts to eliminate prime numbers in sequences to see if we get to a power of $2$.

To avoid prime numbers I simply used $3n+2$ when I  encounter in sequence a prime, but I could consider also $3n$, or to obtain an even number (like original operation): $3n+3$ or $3n-1$, that is the even number that is greater or less than the even number I find with original $3n+1$.

For now I see only one problem: by avoiding primes in the way I have used, I am most likely skipping number sequences that could arrive at a power of $2$ (thus testing that ends positively) even without there being in the sequence a single prime number from which we slowly arrived at the final power of $2$.

There are a lot of small primes.  Since, when you get to a prime, you essentially multiply by $3\times \frac 32$, it's hardly surprising that this throws you out of a lot of paths to $1$.  I don't see anything more to it than that.

@lulu , I can't understand why I essentially multiply by $3\cdot \frac{3}{2}$ when I obtain a prime.

$p\mapsto 3p\mapsto \frac {9p+1}2$.

I/We would like to clarify/explain some things. The Collatz conjecture is if every generated sequences of the original rules always lead to a loop of "4,2,1, 4,2,1 ..." so there is no ending point, only loop[s] (in which the Collatz conjecture is whether the only loop for these rules is "4,2,1...").
In your "prime exclusion" variant, there may be other loops, so we cannot simply state that the sequence will tend to 1, we would have to search for other loops/repeating numbers in our sequence.
From my testing with a few modifications to your code [adding a loop detector and printing whether each number is prime or not] [see below] there seems to be two loops that each sequence falls into:

A 3 long loop which starts/loops back at 4 (our "4,2,1, 4,2,1 ...")
An around 6570 long loop that starts/loops back at 413.

There could be more but that's where my short testing has gotten. While it may not be the solution to either original problems (primes/collatz), we/I still do encourage different ways of "poking around" and maybe this sequence/idea variant may actually help out! But for now, more exploration should be done ;)
import math
from sympy import *

def collatz(n):
    print(n,isprime(n))
    hold = []
    while True:
        f,i = math.modf(n/2.)
        if f==0.:
            n=int(i)
            print(n,isprime(n))
            if n in hold:
                print(n,isprime(n))
                return(len(hold))
            else:
                hold.append(n)
        else:
            if isprime(n):
                #n1=3*n+1   -1
                n=3*n+1   +1
                print(n,isprime(n))
                if n in hold:
                    print(n,isprime(n))
                    return(len(hold))
                else:
                    hold.append(n)
            else:
                n=3*n+1
                print(n,isprime(n))
                if n in hold:
                    print(n,isprime(n))
                    return(len(hold))
                else:
                    hold.append(n)

print(collatz(17))


hi, thank you for your time. Sorry, can you explain me why you talk about loop ($4,2,1$)? I understood that Collatz conjecture always ends positively when in the sequence you get to a power of 2, then you get to 2 and then to 1 and it all ends. The conjecture says that you always arrive at 1 starting with all natural numbers as the initial input to the algorithm.

Anyway, I find your modification to the code interesting, and I will use it to see in the various numbers sequences which prime numbers one finds, which positions they occupy in the sequence and after how many steps from the last prime number one finds a power of $2$. Clearly I will go back to using the original version of the conjecture, without excluding prime numbers. I need to think about this a little more. Thanks for sharing.

When you get to 1, if you keep following the original rules, then 1 is odd -> 1*3+1 => 4, which then goes back to 2 then 1. So if you keep following the original rules, then the generated numbers will keep cycling 4,2,1,4,2,1...

Yes it is clear, let's say that for me there is an infinite running in the algorithm only if there is a sequence of numbers that never contains $1$, therefore never $2$ and therefore never $4$, but neither does any other power of $2$, such as $8$, $16$, $32$, .... the infinite running can be 1) a loop without any power of $2$ in the sequence that repeats infinitely a numeric pattern or 2) a random numbers sequence apparently without any repetitive pattern and without any power of $2$.
